# Django registration form on startpage, without redirect to loginpage

Tags: python, html, django, forms, authentication

I am really new to Django, but have the basics of Python at least. For the summer I am working on a webapp that will work in unison (hopefully) with a fortran code. This fortran code generates data, and together with a registration system, users should have access to a database of the data this fortran code creates.

So far I have a general template for the homepage and now I am trying to implement a registration button and login form for the homepage. From starting page, I want users to be able to press the register button, be redirected to a form which asks for some basic information such as name, email etc. Then they are sent a confirmation email and by clicking a link the account should be activated. 
Next to it, the login button should be there with fields for their username (the email) and password. If username/password is wrong, it should add a text saying wrong username/password but not redirecting to any other page.

For now I am working on the login part only. The problem I am having though is that the page only shows the login button and not the fields to fill out the username and passwords.

Here is the setup of my base.html

```
<div class="page-header">
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1>Hello and welcome to my code!</h1>
  <div class="right">
     {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
     {% endif %}

     <form>
     {% csrf_token %}
     <table>
     <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
     </tr><tr>
         <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
         <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="login" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}"/>
```

Regarding the registration process and user handling, which app is preferred for Django 1.8+? I have heard that django-registration is not updated anymore, and django-registration-redux I am have problems with getting to work due to an error:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

which I can't seem to fix using the normally suggested solutions. Allauth I tried diving in to, but I thought that maybe I can find better alternatives here from suggestions here.

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why are you trying to use an app for registration may I ask? You can easily create a registration form and login / logout views.

Comment: The forms didn't appear to be that easy, and in the example for django-registration-redux it simple looked like it had everything ready for handling users, registration and login.
How would I do it with a registration form instead?

Comment: I wrote an app in my project that does all this. Have a look, and feel free to use the code (AGPL license) https://gitlab.com/Pacodastre/Berou/tree/master/berou/accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.Register, name='register'),

    url(r'^login/$', views.Login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.Logout, name='logout'),
]
```

register.html <-- registration form

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

login.html <-- login form

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def Register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        fname = request.POST['first_name']
        lname = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']

            u = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password, first_name=fname, last_name=lname)
            u.save()

            return HttpResponse("Registration complete! Please head over to the <a href='/login/'>login page</a> to start using your website.")

        return render(request, "app/register.html", {})

def Login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        mobile = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("This user is not active. Please contact support@company.com")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    return render(request, "app/login.html", {})

def Logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

All my templates ( the html files ) are inside my app folder. For the purpose of this answer let's assume the app is called `app`. So the folder structure will be `app/templates/app/` and then the template files `register.html`, `login.html`. This is a stripped down version of a project that I worked on. Hope this helps. I've learned this method of registration and login from YouTube channel of Mike Hibbert. Do a search and watch his videos.

P.S. If you can make the login work it will take you to the localhost:8000/home/ but I haven't provided the url or the view for that over here. Make one on your own.